# multiple windows machine and keyboard layouts

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout

I have 3 windows 8.1 machines. Laptop (Acer), Desktop (HP) and Windows Surface pro (MS). One has English keyboard, one has Danish and one has German Keyboard. Therefore I have added three layouts for my windows: ENG, DAN, DEU. My login ID is hotmail so all my profile and stuff is online sync. Keyboard layouts are different but the language for windows and display I use is English UK.

Problem is if I change my keyboard in one windows and when I login to other one it is also already changed over there. How to fix it? I could not find its solution online.

Additionally on windows surface on touch cover I use deutsch (DEU - German) but while using the screen keyboard I use ENG and that also becomes issue and drives me crazy.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be stopped by changing the Sync Settings of OneDrive on the computer. You can stop syncing all the settings across the Windows 8.1 computers or choose which settings to sync. Please refer to the Microsoft Help article given below and try the suggestions given in it.

[Sync settings between PCs with OneDrive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs)